# Search into multidimensional array comparing two keys without using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, array-key

I have arrays like this:

```
$actions = array(
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f0',
        'is_active' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f1',
        'is_active' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'radio',
        'id'        => 'f2',
        'is_active' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f3',
        'is_active' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'text',
        'id'        => 'f4',
        'is_active' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f5',
        'is_active' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f6',
        'is_active' => 1
    )
);
```

so i need to extract the arrays that has type = 'checkbox' and is_active = 1 only
without any "for loop" ..

Any good solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` with `callback` to return only type which is checkbox.

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($v){return $v['type'] == 'checkbox' && $v['is_active'] == 1;});
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/idAR4

Answer (score 2):

Edit of answer @Rakesh Jakhar

One more condition added as per the question

```
<?php
// Your code here!
$actions = array(
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f0',
        'is_active' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f1',
        'is_active' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'radio',
        'id'        => 'f2',
        'is_active' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f3',
        'is_active' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'text',
        'id'        => 'f4',
        'is_active' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f5',
        'is_active' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'id'        => 'f6',
        'is_active' => 1
    )
);

$filtered = array_filter($actions, function($v){return $v['type'] == 'checkbox' && $v['is_active']==1 ;});
print_r($filtered);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can sue `array_reduce`, [Demo](https://3v4l.org/CnX47)

```
$filtered = array_reduce($array, function($a,$b){
    if($b['type'] == 'checkbox' && $b['is_active'] == 1){
        $a[] = $b;
        return $a;
    }else{
        return $a;
    }},[]);
print_r($filtered);
```